# Swipe down feature in webdriver mobile emulation python

Tags: python-3.x, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, simulation

I am trying to get the swipe down to refresh feature, in webdriver mobile emulation with python. I found locations of two elements and tried to tap, hold and release at latter location. The swipe works on phone for those two elements. This is my code. Is it even possible to replicate mobile behavior to this extent?

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    deviceMetrics = {
        "width":480,
        "height":854,
        "pixelRatio":3.0
        }
    mobile_emulation = {
                # "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.3; HTC One X Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19',
                "deviceMetrics":deviceMetrics,
                "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPD1.170816.004) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            }
    options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    options.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
    # # options.add_argument("--headless")
    
    browser = uc.Chrome(options = options)
    browser.set_window_position(0, 0)
    browser.set_window_size(470,854)
    
    
    browser.get("http://google.com")
    action = TouchActions(browser)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("igu8Pb")
    elem2 = browser.find_element_by_id("hplogo")
    print(elem2.location) #{'x': 160, 'y': 112}
    print(elem.location) #{'x': 175, 'y': 0}
    action.tap_and_hold(175, 0)
    action.release(160, 112)
    action.perform()
```

Comment: https://www.pcloudy.com/developer-and-tester-forum/question-and-answers/how-to-automate-pull-down-refresh-functionality/

Comment: This is the closest link I found, but unfortunately not in python.